# Performance considerations when getting license information for WP app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

## Introduction

I have a `Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight` (WP8.1 SL) based app in the store. Some users complain about performance issues when they have a bad network connection. I searched a bit and came up with the idea that it might be related to `new LicenseInformation()` that gives me the information of whether the app is running in Trial mode or not. The question is, whether this requires network information or not, and whether `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation` is a suitable replacement for a WP8.1 SL app.

## Background and What I did so far

In general, the app does not need a network connection (no data to load, no advertisements, ...). To confirm that I used Fiddler to watch over the network sent by my phone. The result was that no network traffic is generated. However, the problem still persists.

After a lot of research and playing around I got the feeling that this issue might be related to the code part that checks on whether the app is in trial mode or not. I use the following code to check that.

```
var li = new LicenseInformation();
if (li.IsTrial()) {
    ...
}
```

I do this a couple of times during startup. So in case `IsTrial()` requires a network connection this could be the actual issue when there is only a bad connection available. But again, I couldn't find anything using Fiddler. The documentation ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.aspx)) for `LicenseInformation` does not mention whether a network connection is required or not.

Searching around I found that there is an updated interface available for both WP 8.1 SL and also W10M UWP.

```
var li = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
if (li.IsTrial) {
    ...
}
```

Its documentation clearly states that there is no network connection required for that ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.licenseinformation.aspx)).

Even though the docs say that `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation` is also available on WP8 I also found some references that say that you only get a reliable answer for the IsTrial-question when using `new LicenseInformation()` (e.g. [here](https://github.com/markedup-mobi/CurrentAppProxy/blob/master/src/CurrentAppProxy.WinRT/CurrentAppProxy.cs)).

## Actual Questions

- Is `new LicenseInformation()` required on WP8.1 SL, or can I use `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation` as well?
- Does `new LicenseInformation()` require a network connection compared to `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation`?